# How to show the view for specified time in UI in android?

Tags: android, view, timer

I am showing view in my layout if my upstream speed is less than 10000,I want to show that view for 3 more seconds and in mean time I want to check the upstream speed again. If upstream speed is less than 10000 means show the same view in UI else remove that view in UI.

```
if (!((sourceSize == remainingSize)|| (remainingSize == 0)) && upStreamSpeed < 100000) {
            /**
             * 100000 Bytes = 100 Kilobyte
             */
            chatXmppConnectionStatusLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            chatXmppConnectionText.setText("Network low");} 
       else{
            chatXmppConnectionStatusLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: Spawn a separate thread that sleeps for 3 seconds then call runOnUiThread to hide the view

Comment: Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: you can also use CountDownTimer

Comment: can you show me some example with my code? I am really in need of it.

Comment: I have updated in the answer it is working for me

Comment: your answer helped a lot but still I have a doubt. I am using your code in a method which is called by several times , so the new CountDownTimer will create a new object again and again how to over come this issue?

Comment: yes thats why I deleted it is not a right way I think you need to use thread

Comment: can you show me some example?

Comment: https://www.androhub.com/count-down-timer-in-android/

Comment: Using threads is also a costly process right? I am really stuck into it. I am helpless

Comment: check current time to that specific time and according to this set visibility gone and visible

Comment: I don't know how to do that please post your answer and integrate it with my code

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this :

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
   //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
}

public void onFinish() {
    mTextField.setText("done!");
}

}
.start();
```

Comment: What is 30000 and 1000 in CounDownTimer?

Comment: milliseconds with range

Comment: I am using your code in a method which is called by several times. new CountDownTimer will create new object again and again right? how to over come this issue?